# How to create dynamic NHibernate mappings without generating HBM XML files?

Tags: nhibernate, dynamic, fluent-nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I'm working on a dynamic application with NHibernate. My goal is to create dynamic entities (both class type and mapping xml file) based on some data. For example suppose I want to create a `Person` entity dynamically in runtime and on the fly.

I use `Reflection.Emit` to generate class type dynamically. For creating mapping dynamically I used [Ayende's code.](http://ayende.com/blog/3294/dynamic-mapping-with-nhibernate). But unfortunately this code does not work because `mappings` does not have `Classes` property. I tried to code as same as codes of `Castle ActiveRecord` and `Fluent NHibernate` but they generate HBM XML files. As I don't want to generate/create mapping files so I can not use these solutions.

Is there any way that like Ayende's solution not to be forced to generate HBM XML mapping files and just doing everything dynamically and in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate 3.2 has a [mapping-by-code](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-32-mapping-by-code.html) layer that does what you want.

I'm not *sure* if dynamic classes will work, but it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: many thanks, that seems very useful for my purpose. I have one related question about passing type to generic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562685/pass-type-to-generic-method-nested-generic . Would you please take a look at it too?

Comment: @afsharm: Jon Skeet's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method/232621#232621) linked by Matthew in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562685/pass-type-to-generic-method-nested-generic/6563089#6563089) should do.

Answer (score 2):

fluentnhibernate creates hbm in memory just to feed them to nhibernate. fluentnhibernate has the nice automapping feature with costumizable conventions, perfect for this situation. Also in FNH 2.0 they are working to skip hbm for better performance, but normally you'll never see the mappings outside memory.

Sample:

```
Assembly assembly = GetDynamicallyCreatedTypesAssembly();

ISessionFactory sf = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(...)
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.Assembly(assembly)))
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: I wonder if the output of FNH will be read correctly... In particular, regarding assembly and type names.