# Pass type to generic method (nested generic)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dynamic, nhibernate-mapping

How can I invoke following method while I have not `TRootEntity`, but have just its `TYPE`:

`public void Class<TRootEntity>(Action<IClassMapper<TRootEntity>> customizeAction) where TRootEntity : class;`

final goal is to run following code

```
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.Class<MyClass>(ca =>
{
    ca.Id(x => x.Id, map =>
    {
        map.Column("MyClassId");
        map.Generator(Generators.HighLow, gmap => gmap.Params(new { max_low = 100 }));
    });
    ca.Property(x => x.Something, map => map.Length(150));
});
```

It is used to create dynamic NHibernate `HBM`. More info available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556680/how-to-create-dynamic-nhibernate-mappings-without-generating-hbm-xml-files)

As related question see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100760/can-i-pass-a-type-object-to-a-generic-method).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot code Generic methods to run by passing a runtime Type.

Generics need to have the type at compile time.

You may need to use reflection (see answer of mr. Ferreira that point on how to do that).

Comment: +1. It is important to remember that generics are extrapolated at compile time.

Comment: Please see my update. I have added 2 related questions that shows it is possible at least in certain situations.

Comment: both of those related question are solved using reflection. That does not have to work after you compile and surely won't work as fast as a pure generic implementation. Take this for example: `obj.GetType().GetMethod("Find<>").MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke()` - if you send a type that does not adhere to the generic constrains this will compile and fail at runtime.

Answer (score 14):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method) from the great Jon Skeet. You should be able to adapt it to your needs.