# Iterating through a list of types and passing type as parameter

Tags: c#

I have the following problem:

I want to iterate through a list of types and in the loop pass the type as a parameter to a generic function and somehow this doesn't work. I could just hardcode it if there really isn't any way to do it, but that obviously wouldn't be as "pretty" as using a loop.

Generic method:

```
public async Task GenericMethod<T>() where T : class
{
    // Does something ...
}
```

List of types:

```
List<Type> listOfTypes = new List<Type>() { typeof(classA), typeof(classB) };
```

Iteration where the problem occures:

```
foreach(Type type in listOfTypes)
{
    await GenericMethod<type>();
}
```

Error message:

> CS0118 'type' is a variable but is used like a type

And just FYI: This would work (hardcoded):

```
await GenericMethod<classA>();
```

Comment: Read about reflection. You can't do it that way.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6563109/3966756

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable type as a Generic Type Parameter. Maybe consider passing the variable type in the method as a method parameter. Ex:

```
public async Task GenericMethod(Type varType)
{
    // Does something with: varType ...
}
```

also if you need to determine the type of an object at runtime, you need to declare that object as **dynamic**